# Plotting .dat file

Tags: plot, matlab

I'm looking to plot a simple plot with data I've taken from MATLAB in a `.dat` file format. The file has two columns in the order shown below. I would like column 1 to be x and column 2 to be y.

I've been trying to use `tikzpicture` for ages but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated thank you.

I dont know if this is an issue but the columns are huge and have lots of entries. Is that an issue in latex?

```
1.3888889e-03   2.0000478e+01
2.7777778e-03   2.0001440e+01
4.1666667e-03   2.0002877e+01
5.5555556e-03   2.0004785e+01
6.9444444e-03   2.0007160e+01
8.3333333e-03   2.0009999e+01
9.7222222e-03   2.0013296e+01
```

[image: MATLAB Plot]

The picture is what I am attempting to recreate. Here's the code I've simply got to plot the marker points, can anyone point me in the direction of creating a line opposed to all the points. Also adding in more y axis points i.e. every 100oC and grid lines if possible. Thanks

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[legend style = { at = {(0.6,0.75)}},only marks,
xlabel = Time\,/\,hr,xmax = 8,xmin = 0,
ylabel = Temperature\,/\,$^{0}$C,ymax = 600,ymin = 0]
\addplot [thin] table {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Temperature Change in FB}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please, share the code of what you have tried already.

Comment: also remove the empty lines between entries. is that your data file structure?

Comment: I would recommend 2 approaches. The best one for me is using Gnuplot (can take your data exported from matlab) and export in latex. The other could be using this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the number of data points is a problem or not depends on what exactly you mean by 'huge'. But if you've successfully plotted with points already, then it obviously isn't a problem. With regard to the rest:

The `only marks` option will give you just the points. If you remove that, you will get a line.  The default is actually to plot both points and line, but the `thin` option that you've added to the `\addplot` overrides this, giving you just the line. You can also say this explicitly with the `no marks` option.

You can specify the values for y-ticks with `ytick={<numbers>}`. To get regularly spaced ticks, you use the triple dot notation, i.e. `ytick={0,100,...,600}`. Similar for `xtick`.

To get grid lines for the specified ticks, just add `grid` to the `axis` options.

In the code below I also added an example of use of the `units` library for adding units to axis. I also added an additional data value just to get a visible line for the axis limits you had given.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\usepackage{filecontents}
% the filecontents environment writes its content to the specified file
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
1.3888889e-03   2.0000478e+01
2.7777778e-03   2.0001440e+01
4.1666667e-03   2.0002877e+01
5.5555556e-03   2.0004785e+01
6.9444444e-03   2.0007160e+01
8.3333333e-03   2.0009999e+01
9.7222222e-03   2.0013296e+01
8               550
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  legend style = { at = {(0.6,0.75)}},
  unit markings=slash space,
  x unit={hr},
  y unit={^\circ C},
  xlabel=Time,
  ylabel=Temperature,
  xmin=0,xmax=8,
  ymin=0,ymax=600,
  ytick={0,100,...,600},
  xtick={0,1,...,8},
  grid,
  grid style={dotted}]

\addplot [thin] table {data.dat};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```